# How do I Migrate from SQL Server 2000 to MySQL

Tags: sql-server, mysql

I am looking for a way to export data from our PRODUCTION SQL Server 2000 so I can import it into a MySQL server I setup for testing.

I tried having the server generate an SQL script from the enterprise manager, but it is not understood by MySQL. Upon looking to the script with Notepad++ I noticed that it is setup for being loaded into another MSSQL server.

Any ideas on how to make a generic SQL dump that MySQL can understand.

Also I need the data to left on the other server untouched I just need a copy of it.

Answer (score 1):

There is not simplified portability between these database platforms;
With an understanding of the link and a combination of tools it can be done;

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/migrating-from-microsoft.html

Make sure to always keep an up to date backup of your database before trying anything.
good luck, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: If use MS DTS export that data from the server will it leave the original intact?

Answer (score 0):

You could try with a tool like OpenDBCopy that is an opensource database migration tool :

http://opendbcopy.sourceforge.net/

With opendbcopy you can migrate from and to several database type, all that have an avalaible JDBC driver.

I've used this tool often in migration and it's a good database migration tool.

Is written in java and work both linux and windows OS.

There's also many commercial alternatives to openDbCopy(that are simplier) like :

- ESF Database Migration Toolkit  - http://www.easyfrom.net/

Comment: It did not work for me, I had java problems and then after java started working it complained about not being able to see the server.

Comment: you need to download the appropriate JDBC Driver and put it into lib dir, for Microsoft SQL you can Download JTDS driver : http://jtds.sourceforge.net/ , for mysql you can download : http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/3.1.html

Comment: openDBCopy doesn't seem to have been updated since '04. It makes me wonder how reliable it is since it doesn't appear to be maintained any further.

Comment: I had the same problem and decided to try openDBcopy. And, what do you know, it works with some minor config changes. I put it on github at https://github.com/squarepegsys/openDBcopy/releases/tag/0.51